# How do I return an array from an array function using groovy?

Tags: arrays, groovy

How do I return an array from an array function using Groovy? I am currently trying it with the following code but I am getting errors when I execute the code! I want to be able to get values from an array function where I am extracting the data from excel and I want to be able to use arbitrary values retrieved from the function. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
package Check

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class Second {

    static main(args) {
        //def alpo = new String[2][3]
        def alpo = getTableArray("KSuite");
        println "£34." + alpo[1][2]
    }

    public static String[][] getTableArray(String xlSheet) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\KSuite.xlsx"));
        //System.out.println(input.path);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        //System.out.println(xlSheet);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(xlSheet); 
        int ci;//,cj;
        XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
        int jMax=Math.max(r.getLastCellNum()-r.getFirstCellNum(),2);
        int iMax=sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
        def tabArray= new String[sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum()][jMax];
        //System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum());
        //System.out.println(jMax);

        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            ci = i - 1;
            r = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
                XSSFCell c = r.getCell(j, r.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                if(c.getCellType() == 1) {
                    tabArray[ci][j]=c.getStringCellValue();
                } else {
                    tabArray[ci][j]=((float)(c.getNumericCellValue()) + "");
                }
            }
        }
        input.close();
        // return(tabArray);
        // return(cj);

        return(tabArray);
        // return(cj);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
   Caught: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at Check.Second.main(Second.groovy:15)
```

Table KSuite in KSuite.xlsx:

```
Script  Run 
Login,  Yes
Workspaces  No
Users,  Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say as I don't know your input file, and your code is a bit confusing, but as a guess, on this line here:

```
    int jMax=Math.max(r.getLastCellNum()-r.getFirstCellNum(),2);
```

You set the minimum number for the secondary dimension to `2`

then here:

```
    println "£34." + alpo[1][2]
```

You get the 3rd element of the returned array.  I assume it only has length `2`

I also had a go at Groovifying your `getTableArray` method, and came up with:

```
String[][] getTableArray( File xls, String sheetName, int skip=1 ) {
    xls.withInputStream { input ->
        new XSSFWorkbook( input ).with { workbook ->
            getSheet( sheetName ).with { sheet ->
                (sheet.firstRowNum+skip..sheet.lastRowNum).collect { rowIdx ->
                    getRow( rowIdx ).with { row ->
                        (row.firstCellNum..<row.lastCellNum).collect { cellIdx ->
                            row.getCell( cellIdx, CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK ).stringCellValue
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def results = getTableArray( new File( '/tmp/test.xlsx' ), 'Sheet1' )

assert results[ 1 ] == [ 'Workspaces', 'No' ]
```

Comment: I have edited to add the table data present in the table under question

Comment: @user3083447 updated new groovy function...  Try that?  Might need to skip the headers

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have fixed the issue and allows me to retrieve data from the Excel file using the function:

```
package Check

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class Second {

    static main(args) {
    //def alpo = new String[2][3]
        def String[][] alpo = getTableArray("KSuite");
        println alpo[1][1]
    }

    public static String[][] getTableArray(String xlSheet) throws Exception{
        //String[][] tabArray=null;

                            //System.out.println(xlSheet);
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Temp\\KSuite.xlsx"));
                //System.out.println(input.path);
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
                            //System.out.println(xlSheet);
                    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(xlSheet); 
                    int ci;//,cj;
                    XSSFRow r = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
                    int jMax=Math.max(r.getLastCellNum()-r.getFirstCellNum(),2);
                    int iMax=sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
                    def tabArray= new String[sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum()][jMax];
                        //System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum());
                        //System.out.println(jMax);

                    //ci=0;
                    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum()+1; i <= 
                            sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                       ci = i - 1;
                            r = sheet.getRow(i);

                       //int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

                       //cj=0;
                       for (int j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
                           //tabArray[1][1] = "rr";
                           //System.out.println(tabArray[1][1]);
                          XSSFCell c = r.getCell(j, r.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                          if(c.getCellType() == 1) {
                            //System.out.println(c.getStringCellValue());
                              tabArray[ci][j]=c.getStringCellValue();
                                  //System.out.println(tabArray[ci][j]);
                              } else {
                            //println c.getCellType()
                                  tabArray[ci][j]=(c.getNumericCellValue().toString());
                              //tabArray[ci][j]=c.getStringCellValue();
                                  //System.out.println(tabArray[ci][j]);

                              }
                       }
                   }
                    input.close();
                   // return(tabArray);
//                  return(cj);

                return(tabArray);
//              return(cj);
        }
}
```

Output Result:

No

Comment: Just needed to define the variable "alpo" it properly and keep it within the range

Comment: Isn't that kinda what I said in my answer? ;-)

Comment: Yes it is but I tidied by putting the "String[][]" into the def, but since this was not strictly necessary I will give you a +1.

Comment: However I could not get the groovified script to work, so had to retain the original styling for the function!